# BusyBox crond fails to run scripts with "time disparity" error message

Tags: busybox

I've installed BusyBox on my Android 4.1.1 phone and when I run crond, after some time it starts to failing to run scripts with message "time disparity of xxx minutes detected". Is there something I can do to make it work properly?